# Merging rows and updating related foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a current `users` table. A distinct user is defined as when the `email` and `phoneNumber` together are unique. Currently the table  looks like this:

[image]

And another table called `giftee_info` which has the foreign key on column `userId` to `users.id`:

[image]

The `users` table is going to be parsed out into 2 tables: `users` and `user_metadata`. Now a distinct user will be defined by the `phoneNumber`. So you can see in the data above, users with id's 4 and 5 are the same, and have to be merged.

The new `users` table will look like:

[image]

And the new `user_metadata` table will look like this:

[image]

Note how the 4th row has `userId` of 4, so users 4 and 5 have merged to one user.

And `giftee_info` will look like this:

[image]

See how the 3rd row in `giftee_info` contains userId 4, as the user with id 5 has been merged into one user.

The data I've provided is basic. In reality there are many rows, and a user with the same number may have 5 different email address (and so are currently treated as separate users in the current schema).

The part I'm having most trouble with is updating `giftee_info`. So any rows with `userId`'s that have been merged down into one user need to be updated. How can I do this?

Comment: If `phonenumber` can be `NULL`, how can you define a distinct user with this? What if there's more than one user with a null phone number?

Comment: If there's more than one user with null phoneNumber, they are considered separate users. The rows I want to merge are the ones with the same phoneNumber's

Comment: But when we're building the new tables, as I show in my answer, we need a field to relate the rows in different tables. How do we determine which row in the new table matches when the phone number is null, we need another column to relate them.

Answer (score 0):

Since `phonenumber` can be `NULL`, I'm using `externalid` as the unique identifier below.

Start by creating the new `users` table from the distinct phone numbers in the old `users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_users (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, externalid VARCHAR(32), phonenumber VARCHAR(32))
SELECT DISTINCT NULL, externalid, phonenumber
FROM users
```

Then put all the emails into the `user_metadata` table, by joining the old and new `users` tables to get the emails along with the new user IDs.

```
CREATE TABLE user_metadata (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, userid INT, email VARCHAR(100), subscribe INT(1))
SELECT NULL, nu.id, u.email, 0
FROM new_users as nu
JOIN users AS u ON nu.externalid = u.externalid
```

Now you can update `giftee_info` by replacing the old user IDs with the new user IDs.

```
UPDATE giftee_info AS g
JOIN users as u ON g.userid = u.userid
JOIN new_users As nu ON nu.externalid = u.externalid
SET g.userid = nu.userid
```

Once this is all done you can rename the tables so `new_users` is now `users`.